# Resharper: Surround With template to apply for all tags in selection?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way I can make a Resharper surround with template to apply to all tags of a certain type in the selected text? Very common scenario is maybe I have a list of `<a>` tags but I want them to be in a list so I would like to just be able to highlight the list of `<a>` tags and use the surround with, but somehow say surround each `<a>` tag with `<li>` instead of the entire list of `<a>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surround with templates don't allow this - they only surround the current selection, they don't do anything with the content of the selection.

However, you might be able to use a Structural Search and Replace pattern to do this. Under ReSharper → Find → Search with Pattern, you could create a HTML pattern that matches `<a>` tags and surrounds them with `<li>`. Something like the attached image (note the "Replace" button has been toggled) (oh, and also note that I haven't actually tested this )

[image]